# i can't connect a restful to a mysql data base

Tags: java, mysql, rest, database-connection, wildfly

i'm developing a restful web service ,actually i'm using a file  but i want to make a data base connection instead so i can get data from the database instead of a file , i tried to make a database connection but it dosn't work , even the server which is wildfly stopped and stoped deploying the project.
this is the files im using:

DBConnection.java file

```
package com.TP6;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConnection {

 public static Connection dbCon;
 public Statement dbStmt;
 public ResultSet dbRst;

 public static Connection setDBConnection() throws SQLException {
 try {

 System.out.println("Inside DB Connection");

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usermangment",
 "root", "");

 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)

 {
 System.out.println(e);
 }
 return dbCon;
 }

 public void getInsertResutlSet(String sqlQuery, Connection conn)
 throws SQLException {

 System.out.println(sqlQuery);
 String sqlquery = sqlQuery;
 dbCon = conn;
 try {

 dbStmt = dbCon.createStatement();
 dbStmt.executeUpdate(sqlquery);

 } catch (SQLException se) {
 System.out.println(se);
 }

 }

 public ResultSet getResutlSet(String sqlQuery, Connection conn)
 throws SQLException {

 System.out.println(sqlQuery);
 String sqlquery = sqlQuery;
 dbCon = conn;
 try {

 dbStmt = dbCon.createStatement();
 dbRst = dbStmt.executeQuery(sqlquery);

 } catch (SQLException se) {
 System.out.println(se);
 }
 return dbRst;
 }
}
```

The userDao.java : which il using a file to get and insert data

```
package com.TP6; 

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 

public class UserDao { 
   public List<User> getAllUsers(){ 
      List<User> userList = null; 
      try { 



         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         if (!file.exists()) { 
            User user = new User(1, "", ""); 
            userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
            userList.add(user); 
            saveUserList(userList);   
         } 
         else{ 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
            userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject(); 
            ois.close(); 
         } 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }   
      return userList; 
   } 

   public User getUser(int id){ 
      List<User> users = getAllUsers(); 

      for(User user: users){ 
         if(user.getId() == id){ 
            return user; 
         } 
      } 
      return null; 
   } 

   public int addUser(User pUser){ 
      List<User> userList = getAllUsers(); 
      boolean userExists = false; 
      for(User user: userList){ 
         if(user.getId() == pUser.getId()){ 
            userExists = true; 
            break; 
         } 
      }   
      if(!userExists){ 
         userList.add(pUser); 
         saveUserList(userList); 
         return 1; 
      } 
      return 0; 
   } 




   public int updateUser(User pUser){ 
      List<User> userList = getAllUsers(); 

      for(User user: userList){ 
         if(user.getId() == pUser.getId()){ 
            int index = userList.indexOf(user);    
            userList.set(index, pUser); 
            saveUserList(userList); 
            return 1; 
         } 
      }   
      return 0; 
   } 

   public int deleteUser(int id){ 
      List<User> userList = getAllUsers(); 

      for(User user: userList){ 
         if(user.getId() == id){ 
            int index = userList.indexOf(user);    
            userList.remove(index); 
            saveUserList(userList); 
            return 1;    
         } 
      }   
      return 0; 
   } 

   private void saveUserList(List<User> userList){ 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         FileOutputStream fos; 

         fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 

         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
         oos.writeObject(userList); 
         oos.close(); 
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

The userService.java

```
 package com.TP6;     
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes; 
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE; 
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS; 
import javax.ws.rs.POST; 
import javax.ws.rs.PUT; 


import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

import com.TP6.DBConnection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
@Path("/UserService") 
public class UserService { 

     DBConnection dbCoN;
     Connection conn;
     ResultSet rslt;
     String Iuser = "user inconnu ";
     String query;
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao(); 
   private static final String SUCCESS_RESULT="<result>success</result>"; 
   private static final String FAILURE_RESULT="<result>failure</result>"; 


   @GET
   @Path("/user/ID")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public String Usernom(@PathParam("id") String id)

           throws SQLException {

   query = "select nom from user where id=55";

 //  System.out.println("" + query);
   dbCoN = new DBConnection();

   try {
   conn = (Connection) DBConnection.setDBConnection();
   rslt = dbCoN.getResutlSet(query, conn);

   if (rslt.next()) {

   String nom = rslt.getString(2);


   } else {
   return Iuser;
   }

   } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
   } finally {
   if (conn != null) {
   conn.close();
   }
   }

   return Iuser;

   }

   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   } 

   @GET 
   @Path("/users/{userid}") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public User getUser(@PathParam("userid") int userid){ 
      return userDao.getUser(userid); 
   } 

   @PUT 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
   public String createUser(@FormParam("id") int id,@FormParam("nom") String nom,@FormParam("agence") String agence, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) 
              throws IOException{ 
      User user = new User(id, nom, agence); 
      int result = userDao.addUser(user); 
      if(result == 1){ 
         return SUCCESS_RESULT; 
      } 
      return FAILURE_RESULT; 
   } 

   @POST 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
   public String updateUser(@FormParam("id") int id, 
      @FormParam("nom") String nom, 
      @FormParam("agence") String agence, 
      @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException{ 
      User user = new User(id, nom, agence); 
      int result = userDao.updateUser(user); 
      if(result == 1){ 
         return SUCCESS_RESULT; 
      } 
      return FAILURE_RESULT; 
   } 

   @DELETE 
   @Path("/users/{userid}") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public String deleteUser(@PathParam("userid") int userid){ 
      int result = userDao.deleteUser(userid); 
      if(result == 1){ 
         return SUCCESS_RESULT; 
      } 
      return FAILURE_RESULT; 
   } 

   @OPTIONS 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public String getSupportedOperations(){ 
      return "<operations>GET, PUT, POST, DELETE</operations>"; 
   } 
}
```

Actually i just want to want what ois the problem why when i make a data base connection it stops working.

this the console:

```
    20:26:51,986 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
20:26:52,235 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Final
20:26:52,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" starting
20:26:53,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found UserManagment.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called UserManagment.war.dodeploy
20:26:53,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:26:53,856 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
20:26:53,868 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
20:26:53,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:26:53,976 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:26:54,053 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
20:26:54,037 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:26:54,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
20:26:54,061 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
20:26:54,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.20.Final
20:26:54,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:26:54,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:26:54,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:26:54,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.3.Final)
20:26:54,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:26:54,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
20:26:54,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:26:54,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:26:54,505 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/DsBibliotheque]
20:26:54,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/DsBanque]
20:26:54,661 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\Users\Emel\wildfly-8.0.0.Final/welcome-content
20:26:54,689 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
20:26:54,699 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
20:26:54,781 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
20:26:54,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Emel\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
20:26:54,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "UserManagment.war" (runtime-name: "UserManagment.war")
20:26:55,191 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8180
20:26:55,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:26:55,728 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final
20:26:56,055 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
20:26:56,057 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
20:26:56,571 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.TP6.RestApplicationConfig
20:26:56,615 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Connection;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.processDeclaredFields(ResourceBuilder.java:867)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.processFields(ResourceBuilder.java:849)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.fromAnnotations(ResourceBuilder.java:755)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.rootResourceFromAnnotations(ResourceBuilder.java:700)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.<init>(POJOResourceFactory.java:29)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:75)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:400)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:208)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:496)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection from [Module "deployment.UserManagment.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    ... 23 more

20:26:56,630 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "UserManagment.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Connection;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection from [Module \"deployment.UserManagment.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
20:26:56,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "UserManagment.war" (runtime-name : "UserManagment.war")
20:26:56,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment: Failed to start service

20:26:56,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090/management
20:26:56,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090
20:26:56,867 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 5188ms - Started 257 of 314 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 90 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
20:26:56,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
20:26:56,982 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment UserManagment.war (runtime-name: UserManagment.war) in 81ms
20:26:57,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "UserManagment.war" (runtime-name: "UserManagment.war")
20:26:57,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."UserManagment.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./UserManagment

20:27:01,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found UserManagment.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called UserManagment.war.dodeploy
```

PS: im using eclipse , wildfly 8.0 as a server , postman for trying the url,and i have already created the mysql database .
when i delete thedatabaseconnection file and the block of code of database in userservice it works again , this is why il sure that the problem is on the database connection.

just in case you want to ,know what is my target im developping an android application which consumes a restful webservice which gets data from database that's it !

THANK YOU FOR HELPING ME !

Comment: have you included the libraries necessary ? are you using any build tool(like maven for example) or just eclipse web project ?

Comment: Yes i've added the mysql jar , no i dont think that i have a build tool !
i think maybe i need a persistance.xml file or something like this ?

Comment: what is your eclipse version and how did you create the project ?

Comment: i'm using eclipse luna and i've created a dynamic web project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we See an error like `NoClassDefFoundError` , `ClassNotFoundException`,`NoSuchMethodException` it means the JVM searched for a class/method without finding it.

But wait, my project compiles fine, how come it didn't find them ?!!!

To answer I must explain the difference between runtime dependency and compile time dependency.

When A uses B.jar(in your case A is your project and B.jar is mysql.jar) we say that A depends on B(B is a dependency of A), if A can't compile without B but can run without it we say that B is a compile time dependency, normally IDEs don't copy these libraries into the final result(jar or war file).

When A can't run without B we say that B is a runtime dependency, normally IDEs include those into the final result(jar or war file).

In your case mysql.jar is a runtime dependency but I expect you configured it as a compile time dependency which is why your project compiles but can't run.

To fix this we configure it in our IDE properly, for eclipse we do it this way(assuming you already added mysql.jar to Libraries) :

1. Right Click on The project.
2. under `Build Path` choose `Configure Build Path`.
3. on the Left click `Deployment Assembly`.
4. click Add , a dialog will pop up, choose `Java Build Path Entries`.
5. choose `mysql.jar` from there

If these steps go As I expected eclipse will copy `mysql.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib` folder and your issue will go(my eclipse version is Neon, I hope these instructions work with your version).

Some Suggestions :

1. Learn to use a Build tool, I recommend gradle because I feel it's the modern way for building java projects but others are good as well(gradle is used for android :) )
2. You may wish to work with some abstractions over JDBC, specifically ORMs, while not all agree with them I still recommend you take a look, there are standards for them(namely jpa and jdo) and there are many standards-compliant implementations(with non-standard extensions as usual), the most popular ORM in java is Hibernate(but that doesn't mean it's the best As its exceptions are horrible for maintenance)

Comment: thank you very much yes it worked ! thank you for your suggestion too i will try to learn more about the build tool thank you @niceman ^_^

Comment: @Emél glad it helped you ^_^